# change background-image of every child div

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the html below :

```
  <ul class="blocks-list">
    {{#each categories}}  
      <li class="blocks-item">
      <a href='{{url}}' class="blocks-item-link">
        <div class="blocks-item-image"></div>
        <div class="blocks-item-text">      
            <p class="blocks-item-title">{{name}}</p>
            <p class="blocks-item-description">{{excerpt description}}</p>
            <div class="chevron">></div>
        </div>
        </a>
      </li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
```

It will display a "blocks-item" for each "categories".
I want every "blocks-item-image" in the list to have a different background-image. I tried the css below but somehow, all div have the same background-image.

```
.blocks-item-image:nth-child(1) {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/1/300/200");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

css nth-child selector works for group of siblings.

so you need to change your css like this:

```
li.blocks-item:nth-child(1) .blocks-item-image {
      background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/1/20/20");
}
```

so by doing `li.blocks-item:nth-child` your are applying nth-child selector to a group of siblings (`li.blocks-item`) which is the solution of issue in question.

```css
.blocks-item-image{
    min-width:20px;
  min-height:20px;
  background-image: none;
}
li.blocks-item:nth-child(1) .blocks-item-image {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/1/20/20");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<ul class="blocks-list">
    
      <li class="blocks-item">
      <a href='{{url}}' class="blocks-item-link">
        <div class="blocks-item-image"></div>
        <div class="blocks-item-text">      
            <p class="blocks-item-title">First Item</p>
            <p class="blocks-item-description">First description</p>
            <div class="chevron">></div>
        </div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="blocks-item">
      <a href='{{url}}' class="blocks-item-link">
        <div class="blocks-item-image"></div>
        <div class="blocks-item-text">      
            <p class="blocks-item-title">Second Items</p>
            <p class="blocks-item-description">Second Description</p>
            <div class="chevron">></div>
        </div>
        </a>
      </li>
    
  </ul>

</body>
</html>
```